# Type indexed tuple

Tags: c++, templates, generics, tuples

How can you implement a tuple class that accesses elements by type rather than by index?  Something along the lines of this interface...

```
template<typename... T>
class Tuple
{
public:
    Tuple(T... elements);

    template<typename U>
    U &get();               // U is one of the types in T...
};
```

Comment: what if the same type is used twice?

Comment: This class will be used specifically in a use case that uses only one element per type.

Comment: I've done it before - maybe 7 years ago - mentioned it on the boost mailing list at the time but nobody saw the utility and I couldn't be bothered explaining in detail. I used Alexandrescu's Loki library, so there's one way you can do it. If you have a go and hit trouble, then you'll have a proper question worth answering ;-P. Nice thing is that you can provide facilities to return types by index number, Visitor pattern etc.. And re cppguy's concern - you can trivially wrap values into distinct types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you implement `Tuple` with variadic template is something like this

```
// Base case, Tuple<>
template< typename... Ts >
class Tuple {
};

// recursive inheritance :D
template< typename T, typename... Ts >
class Tuple< T, Ts... > : private Tuple< Ts... > {
public:
   // we implement get() by checking wether element type match with
   // request type
   template< typename t >
   typename std::enable_if< std::is_same< t, T >::value, t& >::type
   get() {
     return element;
   }

   // above is not enough since it only check this class's element type,
   // we can check the rest of the tuple by inspecting its the parent classes.
   template< typename t >
   typename std::enable_if< !( std::is_same< t, T >::value ), t& >::type
   get() {
       return Tuple<Ts...>::template get<t>();  // call its parent's get() 
                                                // ::template to shut compiler up
   }       

private:
    T element;
};


Tuple< short, int, float, double, char, std::string > t;
auto x = t.get< std::string >();    //  x will be an empty string.
```

This assume no duplicate element type, if there is it will pick the one on the front most.
If request type is not in Tuple, it won't compile.

Comment: I never thought of recursive inheritance to solve this.  Thanks!